# Data() Jquery Add dinâmicamente

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber o seguinte. Estou utilizando a função data do jquery. Como é criado dinâmicamente o código HTML, eu não consigo atribui o data.

```
//Aqui  tem um each
$('#div').append('<span class="vor" data-tipo_m="'+v.cob_tipo_mapa+'">'+v.cob+'</span>');
```

Eu tentei pegar o ultimo valor da class `.vor` e adiciona a função data. Mas não foi possível.
Então adicionei manualmente, como no exemplo acima:

```
$('.vor:last').data("tipo_m", v.cob);
```

Minha dúvida é, isso irá funcionar em qualquer navegador. Pois o data() do jquery, quando inspeciono elemento ele não aparece.
Já a maneira que fiz crio o atributo e depois pego o valor com data() do jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando `$('.vor:last').data("tipo_m", v.cob);` que você utilizou não adiciona valores e sim os recupera.

Para adicionar utilize algo do tipo: `jquery.data($('.vor:last'), "tipo_m", v.cob);`. Note que para o método `jquery.data(...)` adicionar elementos ele precisa de três parâmetros na sua assinatura.

Veja a referência da API do jquery [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

Não há problema algum em fazer da maneira que você fez. Usar o data é apenas uma alternativa. Note que o jquery atual não suporta navegadores antigos, como IE 6 (não tenho certeza em relação ao IE 7).

Comment: Não há problema algum em fazer da maneira que você fez. Usar o data é apenas uma alternativa. Note que o jquery atual não suporta navegadores antigos, como IE 6 (não tenho certeza em relação ao IE 7).

Comment: Caso a resposta tenho resolvido seu problema por favor a marque  como correta marcando o tick verde. Obrigado ;)

Comment: O jQuery 2.x suporta apenas IE 9+, portanto não suporta IE 8. o jQuery 1.x suporta IE 6+.